# Ruby Do loop and iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

Is there a built-in method for writing record numbers so that I do not have to create a variable and increase it? Just developing practices at this point. `file.recnumber`?

```
<% i = 1%>
<% @files.each do |file| %>

<%= i %>. <%= file %> (<%= file.size %>)k<br /> 
<% i = i + 1%>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `each_with_index`, which passes the index as the second argument to the block.

If you want to do something more sophisticated than `each`, recent versions of Ruby also include a `with_index` method that you can chain onto any Enumerable method to get a version with the index. For example:

```
('a'..'z').map.with_index {|letter, index| "#{index} #{letter.upcase}" }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<% files.each_with_index do |file, index| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, io objects and file objects do have a **lineno** method.

```
File.open("test.txt") do |file| 
  file.each{|line| puts "#{file.lineno}: #{line}"}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to just use an HTML ordered list:

```
<ol>
<% ["one", "two", "three"].each do |file| %>
  <li>file <%= file %></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

Will give you something like the following, which you can easily style with CSS:

```
1. file one
2. file two
3. file three
```